# joomla application is not working on the server

Tags: joomla

I am doing an application in joomla. I have uploaded my application into my server. But I am unable to access the front-end module of my application whereas the administrator part is working properly. I am getting the following issue:

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /fugenx1/public_html/ntutu/ntutu_demo/demo/ on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
Apache Server at fgtpl.com Port 80
```

I am using filezilla to upload my files and folders.
Though 2 days back it was working properly.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to make your files writable permissions also go to admin>>global configration>>server tab

make sure

```
Force SSL = none
```

and try to change port in ftp settings

```
FTP Port =21(default)
```